# Scan list of IP addresses using sockets

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests

I wanted to know if it is possible to scan a list of IP addresses using sockets.
I am having trouble returning list as a string.

```
fp = open("targetlist.txt", "r")
val = fp.readline().split()
print("GETTING BOUNTY:     ", "HOSTNAME", val)

str1 = val

for ele in val:
    str1 += ele

hack = val
```

Also I wanted to use a proxy to scan these ports, Im not sure if this is correct:

```
import socket
import sys
import requests

from datetime import datetime
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
import subprocess

init(autoreset=True)
subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)


print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.YELLOW + "START AT:", (datetime.now()))
print("=============COREXITAL PORT SCANNER=============")
print("")
############# Import Modules. Modules are installed by using " pip install (pkname)"###############
#############Modules are other pieces if code available with python. very helpful to sav time##########
target = input("Enter IP Address:  ")

with open('proxyf.txt', 'r') as f:
    proxy = f.read().splitlines()
proxies = {
    'http': (proxy,)
}



############## Saving input value as a variable####################
hack = socket.gethostbyname(target)

print("Scanning IP", hack)
print("Starting to get target information at: ")


###################You can prin a variable or plain text###########3
t1 = datetime.now()
print(t1)
##############We use the modules datime to print the current time#################
print("LOADING...")
print("")


def starthack():
######################### Fuctions: def means Define. functions are called with the () characters##############
    try:
        for port in range(1, 100):
            r = requests.get(url='https://google.com', proxies=proxies)
            hacking = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            hacking.settimeout(10)
            result = hacking.connect_ex((hack, port))
            if result ==0:
                print("PORT:", port, Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + "    OPEN")
                hacking.close()
                if r.status_code ==200:
                    print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.YELLOW + "STATUS:", Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + "OK")
                else:
                    print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.YELLOW + "STATUS:", Style.BRIGHT + Fore.RED + "BAD")
                print(datetime.now())

            else:
                print("PORT:", port, Style.BRIGHT + Fore.RED +"    CLOSED")
                hacking.close()
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.YELLOW + "STATUS:", Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + "OK")
                else:
                    print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.YELLOW + "STATUS:", Style.BRIGHT + Fore.RED + "BAD")
                print(datetime.now())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(t1)
        print("Canceled")
        sys.exit()

    except socket.gaierror:
        print(t1)
        print("Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting")
        sys.exit()
    except socket.error:
        print(t1)
        print("Error")
        print("ERROR")
        sys.exit()
starthack()

###########Calling a fuction##################33
print("")
print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.YELLOW + "END OF REPORT")
print("2023 - Corexital")
```

Basically I wanted the variable 'hack' to get its value from list of targets and I wanted to use a proxy to check if the port is open.

here is target list:

```
192.168.0.1
55.34.23.53
```

And proxyf.txt

```
152.181.123.216:39310
91.84.11.140:21129
141.100.86.14:81
66.77.17.173:8118
39.5.202.25:8333
165.198.221.62:80
136.39.76.246:8333
134.236.47.129:53281
215.68.155.213:8080
150.198.45.216:8090
```

I am at my wits end here, i'm not sure if i am using proxy correctly to scan for open ports and I cannot return a string from the list, pleas help

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to read all lines of the file and strip any newline characters then we join the IP addresses into a single string, also if you want to use proxies with sockets you gonna need to use `socks` you could do `pip install PySocks`.

Here is your full code:

```
import socket
import sys
import requests
import socks

from datetime import datetime
from colorama import init, Fore, Style
import subprocess

init(autoreset=True)
subprocess.call('clear', shell=True)

print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.YELLOW + "START AT:", (datetime.now()))
print("=============COREXITAL PORT SCANNER=============")
print("")

with open('targetlist.txt', 'r') as fp:
    ip_addresses = [line.strip() for line in fp.readlines()]

ip_string = ', '.join(ip_addresses)
print("IP Addresses: ", ip_string)

with open('proxyf.txt', 'r') as f:
    proxy = f.read().splitlines()

proxy_host, proxy_port = proxy[0].split(':')
proxy_port = int(proxy_port)

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, proxy_host, proxy_port)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket

target = input("Enter IP Address:  ")

hack = socket.gethostbyname(target)

print("Scanning IP", hack)
print("Starting to get target information at: ")

t1 = datetime.now()
print(t1)
print("LOADING...")
print("")

def starthack():
    try:
        for port in range(1, 100):
            hacking = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            hacking.settimeout(10)
            result = hacking.connect_ex((hack, port))
            if result == 0:
                print("PORT:", port, Style.BRIGHT + Fore.GREEN + "    OPEN")
                hacking.close()
            else:
                print("PORT:", port, Style.BRIGHT + Fore.RED + "    CLOSED")
                hacking.close()

            print(datetime.now())

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(t1)
        print("Canceled")
        sys.exit()

    except socket.gaierror:
        print(t1)
        print("Hostname could not be resolved. Exiting")
        sys.exit()
    except socket.error:
        print(t1)
        print("Error")
        print("ERROR")
        sys.exit()

starthack()

print("")
print(Style.BRIGHT + Fore.YELLOW + "END OF REPORT")
print("2023 - Corexital")
```